# Linux Permissions and Ownership for WordPress

Tags: plugins, themes, permissions, ftp

I installed WordPress via ftp upload to our server using my ftp user account. This account is different than the user that runs http/Apache.

I am now trying to install themes and plugins and I am getting FTP popup errors in the WordPress admin UI.

Should WordPress be created on the server with owner:group apache:apache or are there certain dir & file permissions that need to be set (like 777)?

What is the best way to create WP on the server to permit UI ability to install and update themes and plugins?